# How to inject an attribute or an object into a view in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, dependency-injection, django-rest-framework, inversion-of-control

I am kinda new to Django Rest Framework.

I have a `views.py` that looks something like this:

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
  """ My API """

  def get(self, request, path):
    """ Handles GET calls """

  def post(self, request, path):
    """ Handles POST calls """
```

And I have a util class in my package like so:

class MyUtilClass:
  """ Helps out with stuff """

def some_method(self, path):
  print('I will now do things to the path: ', path)

Now, I would like to inject an instance of some other class that does some task that it's supposed to into my view. Something like this:

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
  """ My API """

  _some_util_instance = None # How to inject this?

  def __init__(self, util_instance):
    self._some_util_instance = util_instance # Is this the right way?

  def get(self, request, path):
    """ Handles GET calls """
    self._some_util_instance.some_method(path) # This is why I want this object injected.

  def post(self, request, path):
    """ Handles POST calls """
```

What is the best way to inject such an instance into my views class?

I could not find much about this in the documentation. I am familiar with using DI and IoC Containers. However, I am not sure how Django Rest Framework handles all of that.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Where is this instance coming from, and what are you intending to do with it?

Comment: added some context

Comment: That doesn't really help. Why would that be a class? Why would you need to inject it? Why wouldn't it simply be a function that you import and call?

Comment: It is a class because it has multiple implementations. It needs to be injected to make testing easier. It cannot be a function because there are multiple implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    """ My API """

    _some_util_instance = MyUtilClass()
```

Or

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
    """ My API """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._some_util_instance = MyUtilClass()
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Or

```
MyAPIView.as_view(
    _some_util_instance=MyUtilClass()
)

class MyAPIView(APIView):
    """ My API """

    _some_util_instance = None
```

Or

don't use a class as a container for your utility functions, just define them as module-level functions. This is my preferred approach.

Or

Use static/class methods

```
class MyUtilClass:
    """ Helps out with stuff """

    @classmethod
    def some_method(cls, path):
         print('I will now do things to the path: ', path)
```

Then you can simply call `MyUtilClass.some_method(path)` in the view without creating an instance of `MyUtilityClass`

Comment: None of these examples use dependency injection. I find myself having the same question as OP, and the reason I want to use DI is to avoid having a dependency on the implementation of an interface the view needs to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal and I don't know if this would work for your case, but you can do something like this.
Giving that this is your class

```
class MyAPIView(APIView):
  """ My API """

  _some_util_instance = None # How to inject this?
    
  def get(self, request, path):
    """ Handles GET calls """
    self._some_util_instance.some_method(path) # This is why I want this object injected.

  def post(self, request, path):
    """ Handles POST calls """
```

In your urls.py you could inject the dependencies like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'your/cool/endpoint/',
        MyAPIView.as_view(_some_util_instance=SomeUtilInstance()),
        name='my-api-view'
    ),]
```

I haven't tried but I guess you could do the same in your tests, or just do some monkey patch there.